# Что сделать, чтобы приложение на Go собралось под Native Client?

Tags: golang, native-client

Что сделать, чтобы приложение на Go собралось под Native Client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно перед сборкой задать переменную окружения `GOOS`.

```
export GOOS=nacl
```